# Kerberos, .k5login and sudo

Tags: debian, ldap, kerberos, sudo, root

**Background:** I am using a Debian 7 system which I have integrated with an LDAP+Kerberos system using `libnss-ldap`, `libpam-krb5` and `nscd`. I have modified `sudoers` to permit an LDAP group the right to `sudo` and gain super-user privileges. Hence, I can log in as an LDAP group to manage the machine. This is all working fine, and `ssh` login works well with an LDAP user.

I was just experimenting with a `.k5login` file in the home directory of my user account, `Cosmic Ossifrage`. In the file, I listed:

```
cosmic_ossifrage@REALM.COM
```

which is a valid Kerberos identity. SSH logins as this user continued to work correctly with the `.k5login` file in place.

However, with this `.k5login` file in *my* home directory, I was no longer able to use `sudo -i` to gain super-user privileges. This does not seem to make any sense, since the .k5login is in my home directory, not `root`'s, so to my mind, neither the `root` user, nor the `sudo` command, should be restricted any further than what is present in the `sudoers` file.

However, with the `.k5login` file as above in place, neither `sudo -i` nor `sudo su` were working whereas they were before. Once the `.k5login` file was removed, this functionality was restored and I was able to `sudo` again.

In the log file `/var/log/auth.log`, among the many error messages reported at this time was one from sudo, stating:

```
[pam:sudo] krb5_kuserok failed for user cosmic_ossifrage
```

Did I miss something fundamental in the definition of what a `.k5login` is supposed to do? Is this expected behaviour, and if so, why?

Comment: Are these requirements met on the .k5login: "The .k5login file must contain one principal per line, be owned by user, and not be writable by group or other (but must be readable by anyone)."

Comment: D'oh! I think you may have hit the nail on the head. `must be readable by anyone` might be the issue -- I will have to check and get back to you.

Comment: If this was resolved, it would be nice to know the solution. I'm looking for something similar to this.

Comment: @quux00 The issue was that the network location where the home directories were stored, and hence where the `.k5login` file resided, was restricting access to *only the user concerned* (and root squashing was of course enabled). Adding world readable permissions for the `.k5login` file resolved the difficulties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [Mark's](https://serverfault.com/users/48857/mark-wagner) [comment](https://serverfault.com/questions/608928/kerberos-k5login-and-sudo#comment725461_608928), the `.k5login` file must satisfy the following requirements:

> The .k5login file must contain one principal per line, be owned by user, and not be writable by group or other (but must be readable by anyone).

as per the comments found in the Kerberos [source code](https://github.com/heimdal/heimdal/blob/ef8e4da01035981b228d8d26ca25598dd81bc766/lib/krb5/kuserok.c#L423-L425).

In this instance, the `.k5login` file was not readable by anybody but the `Cosmic Ossifrage` user. The NFS mount on which the user's home directory was stored also enforced root squashing, prohibiting access by even the root user. By making the file world-readable, `sudo` to root functionality was returned.

*(Marking community wiki, as the answer originally came from a comment.)*